# Please help me finding the inverse laplace of the following expression

Tags: calculus

Please help me finding the inverse laplace of

$$
\bar{T}(y,s)=\exp{\left\{-y\sqrt{\frac {as}{b+s}+c}\right\}} ~,
$$

where $a,b,c$ are constants and $s$ is the Laplace parameter.

Steps-wise solution will be helpful.

Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: Your tag is wrong, please tag again.

Comment: @Ian it has been fixed

Comment: sorry i am new so cant get it. please suggest where to tag it